Spring Boot - Unsopported Operation during Login
Hi i'm trying to setup login with my new Spring App but during the get authorities method the application return this error:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
        at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.add(ImmutableCollections.java:147) ~[na:na]
        at it.bluetigers.test_permissions.models.Role.getAuthorities(Role.java:51) ~[main/:na]

Here my Role class:
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "test_role")
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "test_role_authority", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id"))
    private Set<Authority> permissions;

    public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = getPermissions()
                .stream()
                .map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getName()))
                .toList();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.name));

        return authorities;
    }
}

If i remove the authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.name)); line all works fine.
How can i fix this ?
Thanks

Solved changed the getAuthorities method as follow:
public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(getPermissions()
                .stream()
                .map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getName()))
                .toList());
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.name));

        return authorities;
    }

